# how to create a dynamic bitmap array?

Tags: c++, gdi+

How to create a dynamic bitmap array?

I tried it like this:

```
Bitmap* bit = new int(5);
```

But it didn't work out.

After, I tried like this:

```
Bitmap* bit = (Bitmap*)malloc(6);
bit[5] = new Bitmap(sFileName);
```

But it didn't work, too.

**EDIT**

In .h, I have:

```
std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> *CachedBitmap;
```

In .cpp (WM_PAINT):

```
Bitmap* bit = new Bitmap(L"file");
Graphics graphics(hdc);
(CachedBitmap[0]) = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap[0].get(), position.x, position.y);

std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(Bitmap* originalBitmap, HDC hdc)
{

    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    return std::make_shared<CachedBitmap>(originalBitmap, &graphics);
}
```

When I run the program, I have an exception error because `CachedBitmap[0]` is nullptr.

I tried:

```
(**CachedBitmap) = std::make_shared<::CachedBitmap>((new ::CachedBitmap(bit, &graphics))[5]);
(*CachedBitmap[0]) = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap[0]->get(), position.x, position.y);
```

But I have error:

> Gdiplus::CachedBitmap::CachedBitmap: unable to access private member declared in "Gdiplus" class::CachedBitmap"

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Bitmap* bit = new int(5);
> ```

This doesn't work because you are dynamically allocating a single `int` whose value is `5`, and then trying to assign the address of that `int` to a `Bitmap*` pointer.  Obviously, an `int` is not a `Bitmap`, so the compiler does not allow this assignment.

You would need this instead:

```
Bitmap* bit = new Bitmap[5];
```

However, that doesn't work either, because GDI+'s `Bitmap` class does not have a default constructor.  So, you need an array of `Bitmap*` pointers, not an array of `Bitmap` objects.  Which leads us to the next example...

> ```
> Bitmap* bit = (Bitmap*)malloc(6);
> bit[5] = new Bitmap(sFileName);
> ```

This doesn't work because you are allocating only 6 bytes total, but you would need to allocate enough bytes for 6 `Bitmap*` pointers in order for `bit[5]` to hold a valid `Bitmap*` pointer, eg:

```
Bitmap** bit = (Bitmap**) malloc(sizeof(Bitmap*) * 6);
bit[0] = new Bitmap(sFileName);
bit[1] = ...;
...
bit[5] = ...;
```

But, don't use `malloc()` in C++, use `new[]` instead:

```
Bitmap** bit = new Bitmap*[6];
bit[0] = new Bitmap(sFileName);
bit[1] = ...;
...
bit[5] = ...;
```

And don't forget to `delete` whatever you `new` when you are done using it:

```
delete bit[0];
delete bit[1];
...
delete bit[5];
delete[] bit;
```

But, do you really need the array itself to be allocated dynamically?

```
Bitmap* bit[6];
...
bit[0] = new Bitmap(sFileName);
bit[1] = ...;
...
bit[5] = ...;
...
delete bit[0];
delete bit[1];
...
delete bit[5];
```

However, in modern C++ coding, avoid `new`/`delete` manually, use standard containers and smart pointers to handle all of the memory management for you, eg:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bitmap>> bit;
...
bit.resize(5);
bit[0] = std::make_unique<Bitmap>(sFileName);
bit[1] = ...;
...
```

Or:

```
std::unique_ptr<Bitmap> bit[5];
...
bit[0] = std::make_unique<Bitmap>(sFileName);
bit[1] = ...;
...
```

**UPDATE**:

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> *CachedBitmap;
> ```

There is no good reason to have a *pointer* to a smart pointer.  Drop the `*` from the declaration:

```
std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> CachedBitmap;
...
Bitmap bit(L"file");
Graphics graphics(hdc);
CachedBitmap = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(&bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap.get(), position.x, position.y);
```

Or, if you really need an array of smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap>> CachedBitmap;
...
CachedBitmap.resize(5);
Bitmap bit(L"file");
Graphics graphics(hdc);
CachedBitmap[0] = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(&bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap[0].get(), position.x, position.y);
```

Or:

```
std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> CachedBitmap[5];
...
Bitmap bit(L"file");
Graphics graphics(hdc);
CachedBitmap[0] = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(&bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap[0].get(), position.x, position.y);
```

Comment: thx, but for feature
in .h i have:
`Bitmap* gifBitmap;`
how init. in .cpp?
`*gifBitmap = new Bitmap  [6];` is not working

Comment: i edit my ques. with new problem

Comment: @Y0MMY I have updated my answer. But it seems you have a fundamental lack of understanding of what pointers actually are and how they work, so I strongly suggest you stop what you are doing and get some [decent C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) that will cover this topic in more detail for you.

Comment: ok, thx for books, but how init. with new? for example, I get some value, and then I insert it to initialize the array. `int val = GetValue(); std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> CachedBitmap[val];`

Comment: @Y0MMY `std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> *CachedBitmap = new std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap>[val];` but that is trivial if you use `std::vector` instead, like I showed in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just wanted to figure out how to do it through new.